# Browser history not maintained when using backbone history with hashchange

Tags: backbone.js, browser-history

So for a Backbone/Flask app I have I am using Backbone.history to keep history of a certain page, and I am using parts of Flask to route through other parts of the app.

A standard user would flow through my application like this:

1. Load page `/location`; the `/location` page is served by flask and does not contain much javascript. It just displays some buttons.
2. The user clicks on one of the buttons and is redirected to `/room/<id>/charts`; again the application handles the routing to this page, and returns a html page containing the backbone application.
3. When this page is loaded I call `Backbone.history.start()` and I register some routes that should be handled by the backbone app on this page.

Now, when a user goes to several of these routes, and then clicks the back button of the browser, the browser will only go back until the first route that has been loaded by the backbone application on the `/room/<id>/charts` page. Even though I visited the `/location` page before coming to this `/room/<id>/charts` page that initiated the `Backbone.history`.

How can I make the `Backbone.history` work so it will work for the routes handled by the Backbone application, and also for the pages handled by the browser before the `Backbone.history` was started?